# What kind of computer is being used in "Workin on ur problemz"?

Tags: discussion

What are the things between the normal keyboard and the monitor in this picture?

[image: cat on laptop]

This image appears when you strike upon an [error](https://stackoverflow.com/error) on Stack Overflow, and other images too, all with this computer.

Comment: "Iceland" tag missing?

Comment: Good question! Looks like some sort of specialized keyboard, I'm guessing something bookkeeping related because of the big red button. But I can be mistaken.

Comment: This is now the most important question dogging me today.  Thanks.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: 'Dogging'? **Woof!**

Comment: [Larger copy of image](http://www.pantip.com/cafe/wahkor/topic/X8483758/X8483758-11.jpg)

Comment: @Craig: The red button has "Demo" on it, but can't make out any of the other writing.

Comment: @Craig - can you *enhance* it and *rotate the scene*, so that we can read the manufacturer? I'm ready to come back in several hours, the time for the *algorithm* to work.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52566/photo-enhancement-tools/52575#comment-124031 @gno

Comment: I am ashamed that NONE of you recognize the latest CRAY nearly-dumb (Wireless N) terminal when you see it! That cat is now in space! BTW, the key is `PAWZ` if you get near the moon and wish to tweet your location. It could also be yet another modern day knockoff of the Commodore 64, but I doubt it.

Comment: I was _just_ about to ask this. SO triumphs again!

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This is a **V-Tech Talking Whiz Kid Mouse PRO Deluxe**

As illustrated on this [Ebay auction](http://cgi.ebay.com/Nice-Vtech-Taiking-Whiz-Kid-Mouse-PRO-Deluxe-Tested-/290436839612):

[image]

To compare, **three** photos with another cat (and you can see part of the VTech logo on the second):

[image][image][image]

Interesting fact, there are many photos with different cats, because this was taken during a contest. The description of the photo is:

> Maverick, a 7-year-old American
>   Shorthair Silver Classic Tabby, uses a
>   mouse on a toy computer during a
>   preview of the 2006 CFA-Iams Cat
>   Championship at New York's Madison
>   Square Garden, Wednesday Oct. 11,
>   2006.

Comment: Mouse Pro Deluxe and cats... very appropriate.

Comment: Note that if they would have used the original mouse, it would have been easier to find :]

Comment: omg this is an amazing answer, I have wondered the same forever! Excellent research work!

Comment: @Jeff: +1 for starting a sentence with omg in a question about lolcats.

Comment: I knew it was VTech!

Comment: hey, look who won the eBay auction for that machine! Hint: it was me!

Comment: Excellent research, how you find those pictures after all these years?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I searched the event ("Cat Championship", "New York"), with "computer", more or less. Found some low quality images, but hopefully Google image search is there to find similar ones. Mostly coming from Chinese sites, for some reason.

Comment: It's gone now...

Answer (score 21):

Fantastic -- I posted this as a blog entry, with a little bonus, here:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/workin-on-ur-problemz/

Answer (score 16):

That's ridiculous. Everyone knows a cat can't use a computer.

Comment: They can use a computer ... they choose not to. Too much like work.

Comment: Surely they know how to use a **mouse**.

Comment: Those wireless mice might seem defective or strange, though. Especially with the glowing eyes. Of course, though, some cats glow: http://www.guardian.co.uk/science/2011/sep/11/genetically-modified-glowing-cats

Answer (score 8):

It's not a computer, it's a toy.

Notice the flimsy red plastic latch, the handle across the back (unextended), and lack of ports (power, USB, etc.).  It's perhaps ironic that toy computers would have more confusing keys, but those above the keyboard likely select different games/applications.

The keyboard style reminds me of VTech's products.

Comment: Don't mock my EEE!

Comment: MacBook Pros don't have any latch at all. Are they a toy?

Comment: @Andrew: Anything with a flimsy red plastic latch is more likely to be a toy. Do MacBook Pros have a flimsy red plastic latch?

Comment: It's called style.  Sheesh.  Flimsy red plastic latches are all the rage.

Answer (score 7):

I've given up identifying the computer, but I can give you a [bit more information about the photo](http://blogs.reuters.com/oddly-enough/2007/10/11/just-too-obvious-cat-and-mouse/) that I found:

> Zoe, a domestic shorthair cat, touches the mouse of a computer during a media preview for The Cat Fanciers’ Association’s championship in New York October 10, 2007. REUTERS/Shannon Stapleton

p.s. Zoe also [plays basketball](http://cache.gawker.com/assets/images/deadspin/2008/10/zoedunking.JPG) and [walks on a high-wire](http://www1.pictures.gi.zimbio.com/Fancy+Felines+Prep+Annual+Cat+Show+Madison+1FrUKPjOrkNl.jpg)

Comment: I'm more interested on what she is sitting on. Oh no, don't tell me this photo isn't real!

Answer (score 5):

It's an iKibble.

Comment: How many bits does it have?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously  a [Canon Cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_Cat) (designed by Mac creator Jeff Raskin) or maybe a [Wicat](http://www.old-computers.com/museum/computer.asp?c=254) (first UNIX box I ever used).

Answer (score 0):

The servers are obviously Cat a Tonic right now. I'll bet it doesn't even have a TWITTER account. [Uh oh... the crowd is running over here now - and they look *pissed*...]

Answer (score -2):

It is a keyboard for the blind and deaf.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a joke or serious, but I do notice a piece of paper in front of the monitor, which'd be consistent with your suggestion.