# How can I see all the images of the error page?

Tags: feature-request, error-message

So, [SO is down at the moment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203575/why-is-so-not-working), and so when I try to load a question I get an error page with a URL like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/...
```

That page has a title of "Oops!  Something Bad Happened", some explanatory text ([nice job on that BTW, it's very clear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53993/praise-for-the-error-page)), and a funny picture with the caption "WORKIN ON UR PROBLEMZ".

After the first failure, I refreshed the page to see if the problem was transient.  Nope, same error page, but hey!  A different funny picture!  Fun.

I have mild OCD.  Not [Sheldon Cooper-level OCD](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3z_yZ1G1Og), but it's noticeable.  So I refresh to see if there's another picture.  Yup!  I continue refreshing, and I've seen maybe twenty different pictures, and then I get a duplicate.  Oh no, it's random!  But my OCD means I want to see them all, so I keep refreshing.  At this point most are duplicates, but occasionally I get a new one.

I checked the source for a few of the funny pictures and didn't notice any sort of predictable URL pattern that would allow me to harvest them on my own.

I have enough restraint to stop myself, but I'd sure love it if there were a way for me to see all of the funny pictures, and I'd love it even more if I could do it without spamming your error logs.  Since OCD tends to make good programmers, a lot of us have it to varying degrees, so I'm guessing I'm not the only one.

Comment: You can view it without triggering anything in our error logs by just visiting http://stackoverflow.com/error manually

Comment: Those are funny pictures on that page (some funnier than others). I've noticed that there's a glitch in the script, though, that quite often causes two pictures to come in one after the other in rapid succession.

Comment: there is a way to get all the images. ill sort it out tomorrow for you

Comment: @RobH Not a glitch, the script is based on a pair of randomly-generated values.

Comment: What's the point of having one picture come up and then replacing it with another one?

Comment: I've gotten a couple downvotes on this question.  As I'm fairly new as a contributor around here, it's resulted in a 20% decline in my reputation.  Sad face!  Would the downvoters care to explain?

Comment: @blue looks like status tags are not migrated, this was [meta-tag:status-declined] - leaving it out means you reconsider the request? ;)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

OK, here are all 34 error cats! (click to enlarge)

**[Community User](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) Exposed At Last**

[image]

**[Adam](https://stackexchange.com/users/37099)'s cat lolling around**

[image]

**[Brent Ozar](https://stackexchange.com/users/13381/brent-ozar)** (thanks Martin for cracking this one up!)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Benjamin Dumke-von der Ehe aka [balpha](https://stackexchange.com/users/40051/balpha)**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**[Oded](https://stackexchange.com/users/1190/oded)**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**[Emmett](https://stackexchange.com/users/1998/emmett)**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**[Nick Craver](https://stackexchange.com/users/7598/nick-craver)**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**[David Fullerton](https://stackexchange.com/users/32917/david-fullerton)**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Nick and balpha creating code together**

[image]
[image]

**[Marc Gravell](https://stackexchange.com/users/11975/marc-gravell)**

[image]
[image]

**[Jarrod Dixon](https://stackexchange.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon)**

[image]

**[Kevin Montrose](https://stackexchange.com/users/29738/kevin-montrose)**

[image]

**[Kyle Brandt](https://stackexchange.com/users/37483/kyle-brandt)**

[image]

You can see random dev-cat [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/XAYnF/2/) if you like, and in case they add new picture, feel free to edit it in here too. :)

Thanks [Manishearth](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178438/manishearth) for the great help with names!

Following [special request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203583/eeek-stack-exchange-devs-have-devoured-the-lolcat#comment649783_203683), here is Mr. Marco Cecconi workin on ur problemz:

[image]

Comment: Talk about dedication.

Comment: @JoshC I couldn't resist [the challenge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203583/eeek-stack-exchange-devs-have-devoured-the-lolcat#comment649074_203583)!

Comment: Naturally the follow up question is, do you know how the JS actually works? :)  (that is all the current error-cats, FYI; nice job)

Comment: Okay now name all of them :)

Comment: @Kevin after half hour of staring at your marvelous code I gave up! Guess I *could* crack it by spending some more time but it would just ruin the mystery! :(

Comment: @Kasra now *that's* a challenage! Hmm... face detection code anyone?

Comment: @Kasra harder than I thought... [first one I checked](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/error-cats/381472803.jpg) turned out to be [bolshevik muppet](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dUpzF.png)!

Comment: I've been called a muppet before, but never a bolshevik!

Comment: So you're just saying it never happened before @Oded?

Comment: @Bart - Indeed that is what I am saying. I'm just part of the community.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd 34 is all there is, I managed to partially deobfuscate and derandomize the code [here](https://login.corp.google.com)

Comment: @Oded I had a suspicion it's you - but don't you work from home in England, far away from the office at NY? Anyway blame Google, not me! :-P

Comment: @Manishearth that's internal Google domain, I don't have access... does it mean you work for Google now? Wait... you made Oded into a bolshevik muppet?!

Comment: And @Kevin, you might want to see Manishearth's comment above too? See the fixed link [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203583/eeek-stack-exchange-devs-have-devoured-the-lolcat/203683#203683). (Still curious about the source of the code; getting all combinations is different from finding the reason...)

Comment: Right [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203583/eeek-stack-exchange-devs-have-devoured-the-lolcat/203683#203683), @ShaWizDowArd.

Comment: Sure, but we did have a summit in April (and another on a few weeks ago), in NYC, where (and when) those were taken :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Nope, that was on my clipboard. Oops.

Comment: @Oded oh the good life of business travels... ;)

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I think I got it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203692/178438 (is the last one you?)

Comment: You forgot the cat!

Comment: @Manishearth let's merge our efforts somehow?

Comment: The one you both haven't figured out is Brent Ozar I think.

Comment: @MartinSmith he has no picture in the team page, is it based on [this](http://stackexchange.com/users/13381/brent-ozar)?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I'm not sure of his exact role (consultant I guess?) but I know he's involved in the SQL Server side. See [for example this blog post](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/11/how-stackoverflow-scales-sql-server-video/)

Comment: +1 to @Martin - he knows his SQL people as well as his SQL ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Feel free to copy my answer and ping me for deletion.

Comment: @Manishearth OK, will just copy the names you found. Great work!

Comment: @Manishearth done!

Comment: Does anyone know what that laptop is?

Comment: @aalaap https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309105/what-kind-of-computer-is-being-used-in-workin-on-ur-problemz

Answer (score 22):

The element of surprise on that page is very much intentional, so (despite the fact that I also spent some time refreshing https://stackoverflow.com/error this morning), I have to decline this.

On the upside, https://stackoverflow.com/error allows you to get the next (random) picture without generating an actual error.

Comment: I think I hate you for shutting me down so unequivocally, but OK.  :( :)

Comment: Prepare yourself for scripts written to hit /error repeatedly until they have reached a five 9s probability that they have seen all unique error images.

Comment: It already seems very slow. Any tips on how to get the cat to stay when the loading is complete?

Comment: Hmmm @Anna, your "decline" appears to have been declined, so I've changed my accepted answer. :P

Comment: @JakeRobb Totally fair. :)

Comment: Hmm.. so is this [meta-tag:status-disputed]? ;-)