# How come the Community diamond user is wearing a hat?

Tags: support, community-user, winter-bash

Just been reviewing to see if I could hit an audit, and I did. Community diamond is wearing a hat. How did that happen? Who opted it in to Hats, and then chose which hat it should wear?

[image: Community with hat. Handrawed circle and Christmas Holly]

Comment: It's self-aware and started to want to change its name to "Skynet" - we hope to have it under control soon - if not - we advise anyone on the network called John or Sarah Connor to start running :p

Comment: Whew. At least Jon is safe then. A machine can't make a mistake like that...

Comment: Community is clearly batman.

Comment: There is a Sarah Connors. I guess she's safe too. Oooh. And a Sara Connor.

Comment: Community user downvotes and deletes spammer accounts. It's a silent guardian. A watchful protector. A dark knight.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Poetic. I can even see how the hat fits, but who fitted the hat?

Comment: Ummm... Alfred?

Comment: .... a cartoon character?

Comment: @BilltheLizard Alred is one of the SO developers? I'm not of first-name terms with any of them. I see Community has 97 hats beginning with S, so it seems a lot of spammy stuff (your mention of downvotes, else I'd not have known) daily. Four distinct hats already.

Comment: Oh man, you *need* to watch [Batman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Pennyworth)...

Comment: @JonClements I didn't read that as (John or Sarah) Connor. 15-17 John Connors should start worrying, including the real one, apparently.

Comment: @Braiam He's too old to be an SO developer, surely. He was old in 1972, when I saw him on TV, he must be, like, ancient now.

Comment: Hmm...that means... **HE'S A REAL PERSON, HE ALSO KNOWS THAT HE SHOULD WEAR A HAT IN THE WINTER**.... *or otherwise, we're all bots?*

Comment: @KevinGuan cough, Community is a girl...

Comment: @Braiam: Ahhhh, forgot that. You should say this earlier, before I can't edit my comment :(

Comment: @JonClements Jon Skeet will save us.

Comment: Hm. I thought the answer was simply, Every! Body! Gets! A Hat! Anyway, Community is actually a unicorn, as seen [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311135/1016716), so I'm not sure how they can be a batman at the same time.

Comment: Already has the 250-vote hat on Superuser. First of that hat. It's also left the server-farm and found itself an Android device to vote 10 times on.

Comment: @BillWoodger How is it even possible that Community voted via Android/iOS? Do moderators have acces to Community's votes (I always thought it was a bot)?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[Moderators can (and will) set Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159296/213575)'s ([user id -1](/users/-1)) hat at will, so long as she has earned it in a faithful way.

Comment: Thanks, Alfred. I shouldn't worry that the Batman was not earned on SO.