# Does Community use the Android or the iOS app?

Tags: discussion, community-user, winter-bash-2017

I took a look at [Community's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community#); it was wearing a hat which can be earned by "vote on seven questions or answers using the Android or iOS app" .

[image]

I was wondering how Community got that hat.

First I wondered how Community wore hats but this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312354/how-come-the-community-diamond-user-is-wearing-a-hat) answered it, but I couldn't find how it got that [Too Cool](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/too-cool) hat.

Comment: no its not a duplicate , I am asking how it got that hat , not how it wore the hat

Comment: I'm told she uses an iPhone for unhinged comments and moderation actions in the mornings and SO employees have to clean up after her the rest of the day. They all use Android phones, so the answer is it's both.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Someone needs to pry that iPhone away from her before she starts a war with Yahoo! Answers.

Comment: Er, can I request either a Windows app, or have the hat removed? I'd rather have the Windows app, though.

Comment: @IInspectable [Windows Phone is dead](https://www.theverge.com/2017/10/9/16446280/microsoft-finally-admits-windows-phone-is-dead). If you want to remove the hat, just opt out of Winter Bash.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Windows Phone has been dead for *years*. You are probably referring to Windows 10 Mobile. Which may be dead, but is just one of the targets for the Universal Windows Platform. Give use a regular desktop store app, and be done with it. It'll run on Windows 10 Mobile, too (when manifested to support it). As for your second sentence: Are you seriously suggesting, that a solution to not losing a competition is to not participate? I mean, *seriously*?

Comment: @IInspectable [Microsoft removed the most useful app for Stack Overflow from the store recently](https://www.theverge.com/2017/12/19/16797358/microsoft-google-chrome-windows-store-removal) (I don't understand why we even need an app for Android/iOS let alone Windows desktop)

Comment: Community is apparently 'Not a Robot', according to her profile, so you could ask her directly. I don't have that badge, so I might actually be a robot, except the disguise is so good that even I don't know it!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/295232), the Community user

> - Own[s] downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
>
> ...
>
> - Owns up/down votes from [very active deleted users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/user-was-removed)

Those votes/flags can be cast from the official apps. I'm not sure if this is the way the Community user obtained that hat, but at least it's possible.

Comment: And those votes probably have an app / desktop origin. Quite possible +1.

Comment: **TL;DR**: Community may use desktop, Android **and** iOS.

Comment: @Zanon Sometimes at the same time from opposite sides of the world!

Comment: As there are no official confirmation , I guess this is the right answer . The first part  `Own[s] downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted`  is not possibly right because ,the downvotes are auto generated and might not have generated from android/ios .The second part  `Owns up/down votes from very active deleted users` might be right answer to the question .