# "Something bad happened" instead of "Page Not Found" in Jobs tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, 404-not-found

When going to non-existent job, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/1 I am greeted with a lol-dev:

> [image]

(aka "Oops! Something bad happened!" aka 500 Internal Server error)

While it's much more funny than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/-1):

> [image]

I think it's better to send the familiar 404 Page Not Found response header when, well, requesting a page/job that does not exist.

Comment: And if you refresh the page, you get different images that are all funnier than the polyglot, but less impressive.

Comment: It just occurred to me that they probably don't want people refreshing on pages that automatically send bug reports... My bad.

Comment: @skrrgwasme believe me, you should not feel bad reloading that page just to see the different pictures. You don't want to know how many times I did it when writing [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311135/447356). :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report! We deliberately had this configured to throw an exception so that we could catch any pages we missed during the jobs tab integration work.

We've now changed that to be a 404, so you'll see the not found page instead. No more fun images for you! :)

Comment: Thanks, will go looking for fun elsewhere... ;-)