# Stack Overflow redirects to an error page: "Server Error in '/' Application"

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I try to navigate to stackoverflow.com, it automatically redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/.

The error is:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An exception occurred while processing your request.
>   Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom
>   error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

[image]

Update : Error is fixed now. If it is possible please can employee explained what happened? Too much traffic?

Comment: The same is happening for me currently

Comment: <XAMPP browser tabs, "redirects to"> Found the non-ASP.NET developer.

Comment: It looks fixed now, not getting the redirect anymore

Comment: Error is fixed now. Back to work!!!

Comment: StackOverflow was down and it was like a nightmare.

Comment: *If it is possible please can employee explained what happened? Too much traffic?* Nah. Someone must've missed the coffee. Or, they didn't use enough of jQuery there. It's great...

Comment: This is a usual 500 - internal server error in ASP.NET - something must have gone wrong with their controllers. Possibly a wrong try catch.

Comment: @IshamMohamed - a 500 error can have many many many different reasons. Best not to speculate, in particular when not familiar with the specific setup of hardware, software and application code ;)

Comment: @oded agreed but I don't this specific error comes when hardware failure.

Comment: @Isham This came from code beneath ours. There is no try/catch we could possibly add (and what would you do after you couldn’t load the assemblies anyway?). Our code never even ran. You’re just missing a ton of context here and basing a lot of assumptions on a tiny bit of information.

Comment: correction : I don't **think** this specific error comes when hardware failure.

Comment: @NickCraver yeah that's what I have commented for the below answer. I used a wrong wording by "wrong try catch". I should have used just try catch. There is no correct try catch and wrong try catch.

Comment: @Isham a try/catch is wrong here, which is why Microsoft didn’t add one. The inability to load the application you’re trying to host is fundamentally a fatal and unrecoverable error, and it’s correctly allowed to be fatal.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The servers where the errors happened just got patched. The running theory is that that in some cases, when app domains that existed *before* that patching tried to load new assemblies *after* the patching, there was some conflict that prevented that from working.

```
Exception type: FileLoadException 
Exception message: Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set
    from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)
```

This is so low-level that you didn't even get our [custom error page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311133/how-can-i-see-all-the-images-of-the-error-page/311135#311135) if you hit an affected server (which wasn't all of them, so not everybody saw any issues).

We'll look deeper into the causes later, but the issue is fixed for now and it's late at night for our SREs in the U.S.

Comment: Agreed. Put a try catch when you deal with `System.IO.File`. And its recommend to perform <bindingRedirect> when patching files referenced in .config file

Comment: I am not a ASP.NET developer. But if you handle FileLoadException it will redirect to custom error page. Isn't it? I mean if you write the redirection code on catch part of FileLoadException, won't it redirect to custom error page?

Comment: "it's late at night for our SREs in the U.S." One of the mod message replies from yesterday is, uh, surprisingly relevant here.

Comment: @I: balpha is saying that the custom error page can't be loaded *because* of this exception.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an update/thoughts on this:

In my opinion there were 2 levels of failures here:

1. A patch brought down some web servers.

   - I don't really care about this one much. Crap happens. That's *why* we canary a few servers to shake these things down. The real error is...
2. ***You saw that a patch brought down some web servers***.

   - This one is bad and needs fixing ASAP.

What should have happened was us waking up to 2 downed canary servers, but instead you saw a yellow screen of death. The reason for this is the URL you're looking at. The `HEAD` request our load balancer (HAProxy) makes gets a `302`, not a 500. The response HAProxy gets (just as you did) was a redirect to `/error`. But it doesn't care about the `Location` header, just that valid `302` response. By default, a 200-300 (`(2|3)[0-9][0-9]`) is treated as valid in the check response.

In reality that should never happen. Anything not a 2xx should be treated as an error. I've just finished a puppet test and PR we'll likely deploy tonight or tomorrow that will correctly remove 300s from being valid in this check. Users should no longer see a YSOD once we finish rolling this out (we'll want to enable it a bit slowly per-backend to test as we go).

Comment: So, there are no valid 302 by the backend?

Comment: @Braiam not *on the homepage*, nope.

Comment: The web hosting technical speak goes a bit over my head. Are you saying that the load balancer should have noticed these particular web servers had gone down and stopped routing traffic to them? Conceptually, that makes the most sense to me.

Comment: @CodyGray yep, absolutely correct. The settings were not constrained enough (by default) on what is a valid health check.