# Where did the "Workin on ur Problemz" go?

Tags: bug

Recently, (by which I mean RIGHT NOW), I had an error: (Resolved already)
[image: Server Error]
While waiting for this to be resolved, I came across [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311133/how-can-i-see-all-the-images-of-the-error-page/311135#311135).

I tried to go to https://stackoverflow.com/error, but I get a boring error page. Where can I see those guys (and cats) again? :)

Comment: SO runs .net on an  IIS.server. If nothing works, that is what IIS serves you. There is no way a custom error page can be rendered in that case. Not if the loadbalancer decided that the server is available to serve requests

Comment: The reason you get the "boring" error message is because "fun" is too offensive these days, and it's not worth the hassle of having to deal with people complaining.

Comment: @musefan that is a shame. Damn. Any hope?

Comment: The error message indicates it tried to serve a custom error page but that itself had an error.

Comment: They removed custom error pages when they unified themes across sites. Because [SO hates fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Comment: @MartinSmith so I learned there. Yes.

Comment: Nobody's working on our problems anymore. :-(

Comment: The cute error pages were probably just removed in an outbreak of "professionalism".